# Does "just" here mean "only" or "not for a long time"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "just" here mean "only" or "not for a long time"?

Context:

As the infant develops he begins to establish internal maps of the world and, having experienced touch, he develops a way of imagining how that world must feel, even when he is just exercising his visual system.

Comment: "Just" here limits what follows.  This is Sian Ede's claim that infants "imagine" how things feel to touch even when they're only using their "visual system."  Naturally this is based on Ede's ignorance of what the human "visual system" is.  Read some Oliver Sachs to find out about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "only".

Rephrasing:

> Vision comes later in a baby's development than touch.  It is natural for a baby to relate his visual perceptions to his tactile perceptions, since the tactile came first.  Let's imagine a no longer newborn baby looking at an object without touching it.  He naturally tries to connect his visual perception of the object to an imagined tactile perception of it, even though he isn't physically touching it, and is only using vision.